# chrome.proxy: How to bypass the system proxy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am trying to create a simple extension which configures Chrome to bypass the system proxy for a list of IPs/domains. I tried to accomplish that by writing the following in `background.js`. However, this did not work: requests for `stackoverflow.com` still go through the system proxy, as if `bypassList` was empty.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var config = {
        mode: "system",
        rules: {
            bypassList: ["stackoverflow.com"]
        }
    };
    chrome.proxy.settings.set(
        {value: config, scope: 'regular'}, function() {});
});
```

I noticed that using `fixed_server` together with `bypassList` as seen in the [examples in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy#overview-examples) works. This lead me to the conclusion that the `system` mode ignores `bypassList`. Is this conclusion correct? In the documentation I see no mention that the list is used only in some modes.

If `system` and `bypassList` do not currently work together, how could an extension make Chrome not use the system proxy for a set of IPs/domains?

Comment: Judging by the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/proxy/proxy_api_helpers.cc?type=cs&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=327) you're right apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I got a trick for you to test this, Find any Dead Proxy and set up in System Proxy and try to use your extension. If The Stackoverflow.com is not working, bypassList isn't work on System.

For Your Information From [Chrome.Proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy#type-ProxyConfig) Documentation :

> In system mode the proxy configuration is taken from the operating system. This mode allows no further parameters in the ProxyConfig object. Note that the system mode is different from setting no proxy configuration. In the latter case, Chrome falls back to the system settings only if no command-line options influence the proxy configuration.